# QT framework processing gzip payload

Tags: qt, qt5.5

Is there any library to uncompress the server responses which is sent gzip compression. I tried to uncompress from zlib library, But that is throwing compilation errors.

Comment: Requesting an external library is off topic

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `qUncompress()`.

Or https://inqlude.org/libraries/karchive.html